# how to list all the files of a custom directory

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I want to let the user choose a courseName from a list and show all the files under this directory, how can i achieve that? i am struggling with finding a way to show all the files of a specific course.
here is what i've done so far:

**views.py**

```
def showDocuments(request):
    if request.POST:
    if Document.objects.filter(courses__exact=request.POST["course"]).exists():
        print(request.POST["course"])
    else:
        print("there is no files for this course yet!")

    documents = Document.objects.all()
    courses = Course.objects.all()
    context = {
        "documents" : documents ,
        "courses" : courses,
    }
    return render(request , 'dashboard.html' , context )
```

**models.py**

```
class Document(models.Model):
    #to do : enum class ! 
    DB = "data structure"
    SF = "software enginering"
    DS = "discrete structure " 
    WD = "web dev"
    OPTIONS = "options"
    courseChoices = (
        (DB , "data structure"),
        (SF , "software enginering "),
        (DS , "discrete structure"),
        (WD , "web dev"),
        (OPTIONS , "options"),
    )
    courses     = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=courseChoices, default=OPTIONS)
    description = models.TextField(help_text="A little description can be very helpful for others!")
    document    = models.FileField(upload_to=content_file_name)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.document)

    def content_file_name(self, courses):
        file_path = "documents/{courses}/{filename}".format(
            courses=self.courses, filename=courses)
        return file_path
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
       <select id="crs" class="custom-select custom-select-sm" name="course">
          <option selected>option</option>
          {% for obj in courses %}
                    <option value="{{ obj.courseName }}">{{ obj.courseName }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: Does your `showDocuments` has extra parameters (the name of the course)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i am somehow supposed to get it from the user using request.post[] as far as i know right ?

Comment: yes that is a possibility (although typically for searches one uses a `GET`, since then one can share the search URL). What is the name of the `<input name="...">` element (so the key that maps on the element to search)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've just updated my question please have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my solution:

```
def showDocuments(request, *args, **kwargs):
    """ shows all the files of the requested course  """
    crs_names = CoursesNames.objects.all()
    context = {
        "crs_names": crs_names,
        "files": [],
        "not_found" : "",
    }
    if request.POST:

        file_name = request.POST["course"]
        not_found = "There are no files for {0} yet!".format(file_name)
        documents = Document.objects.all().filter(course_name__courses__iexact=file_name)
        context["documents"] = documents
        context["filename"] = file_name

        documentObjectList = Document.objects.all().values_list("document").filter(course_name__courses__iexact=file_name)
        queryset = CoursesNames.objects.filter(courses__exact=file_name).exists()

        if queryset:
            while len(context["files"]) > 0: context["files"].pop()
            for i in documentObjectList:
                context["files"] = i
                print(context["files"])
            if len(context["documents"]) == 0: context["not_found"] = not_found
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```